# How to make interface to be used by Clients : Android

Tags: android, service, interface, frameworks

I want to create an Android framework service and publish a listener interface to update clients on updates. I don't want to make register_XX() & unregister_XX() methods for applications to provide listener reference .What i want is , applications simply implement that listener interface and without calling any register/ unregister method gets notified of changes.

How can i implement that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there any good reason against register/unregister? if you call an interface `*Listener`, i would expect to register/unregister it (from a dev point of view).

i think you can achieve your goal with some abstract class AbstractListener, that registers itself in the constructor - but that's not nice from an architectural point of view and doesn't work around the unregistering.

e.g.

```
public abstract class AbstractUpdateReceiver {
  public AbstractUpdateReceiver() {
    register();
  }


  public abstract void onReceive(Update anUpdate);

  // optional, only the user should react on registering
  public abstract void onRegistered();

  // optional, only the user should react on unregistering    
  public abstract void onUnregistered();

  private void register() {
    //...do register
    onRegistered();
  }

  public void unregister() {
    //do unregister
    onUnregistered();
  }
}
```

the `on(Un)Registered` calls and implementation are not necessary, if the whole registration process should be hidden from the implementing application. but for the unregistering, the user still has to call `unregister()`, as long as your framework doesn't provide anything like `clearReceivers()` or `clearReceiver(AbstractUpdateReceiver receiver)`

another (much) nicer solution without anything like registering/unregistering the implementation into the framework from the implementing application would be a factory doing the whole job instead of an abstract class. in that case, you have to split the abstract class into a normal class and an interface, the normal class provides and handles the registration, while the interface provides a method for `onUpdateReceived`. then you'll have the factory, that creates and returns the class from the framework.

```
public UpdateReceiver createUpdateReceiver(IUpdateReceiver wrapped) {
  UpdateReceiver receiver = new UpdateReceiver(wrapped);
  receiver.register(); //or register directly into a non-static factory
  return receiver;
}
```